# Shibboleth Password with LDAP - no login screen

Tags: saml-2.0, openldap, shibboleth

My OpenLDAP installation is working perfectly fine in my sample applications and even works well as a login service for my Linux installations.

Now, I want to add Shibboleth SAML on top of the OpenLDAP service (same machine).  I followed the installation and configurations instructions on the [IdP 3 wiki](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/Installation) through the end of the [AuthenticationConfiguration](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/AuthenticationConfiguration) page.  Everything starts up fine on my Tomcat 8 server and I am able to see the basic `http://<server>/idp` and `http://<server>/idp/status` pages.  I configured the `ldap.properties` and all of the authn configuration files.

However, the problem is that I cannot get the `login.vm` page to display.

I can see the pages at:

- `http://<server>/idp/Authn/RemoteUser`
- `http://<server>/idp/Authn/X509`

Both of these give me an error (which is fine as I am not using these):

> No conversation key found in request

What am I missing to get the login page to display?  I tried using the path of `/idp/Authn/Password` and get a 404.

Help appreciated as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around and jumping into the Shibboleth Users mailing list (which is phenomenal, btw) I got things working.

Turns out **I had the configuration working the whole time!**

The problem was that I did not understand that Shibboleth does not provide you with default login capabilities and you **must** initiate a login request from a Service Provider.  Once I set things up on [testshib.org](http://www.testshib.org) for Identity Provider testing it all worked perfectly fine.

If anyone else is running into this, jump to [testshib.org](http://www.testshib.org) before getting too frustrated.

Here's what you do:

1. Set up the core for your IdP following the [wiki instructions](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/Installation)
2. Grab your IdP metadata and [register](http://www.testshib.org/register.html) (instructions provided on that link)
3. Follow the instructions to [configure the Service Provider](https://www.testshib.org/configure.html) on your IdP (following the **Post install IdP Config** instructions that are provided on that page)
4. Restart your container (in my case I just used the Tomcat 8 manager to reload)
5. Go to [testhib.org's Service Provider](https://sp.testshib.org/) and enter in  your Entity ID
6. Click the *Go!* button and you will get your login screen

From that point you can troubleshoot any errors you run into on your own as it is out of scope for this particular post.  I had a few errors and found things here, on YouTube and on online documentation to fix my LDAP connection errors.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue but after register and configuring the IdP with testshib I am getting "Unable to locate metadata for identity provider"  what authentication method are you using? do u have a LDAP server configured on the server? will be great if you can provide a link to resource that you used to install, I have been thru shibboleth 3 doc multiple time with no help

Comment: Yes, I have LDAP on the server itself.  I used http://www.learnitguide.net/2016/01/configure-openldap-server-on-rhel7.html